# Shebang in awk files

Tags: bash

I have a bash script from which I want to call an awk file.

How would I call the awk file `fire.awk` and what should I have at the beginning of `fire.awk`.  I have seen `#!/bin/awk -f` but unsure whether it is usual practice.

Why do people include `#!/bin/awk -f` in the awk file ?

Comment: This might help you https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Executable-Scripts.html

Comment: @rowboat, with `gawk`, one should rather use [`-E`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Options.html#index-_002dE-option) instead of `-f` though.

Comment: Why the focus upon `-E` ?

Comment: Why doesn't the question match the headline? Please fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to call awk script from shell script, you have two/three solutions:

1. The awk script inside the shell script

File `foo.sh`:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

awk '{print}' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Useful if you have a really short awk script.

Awful, even with line breaks, if you have a big awk script. IDEs do not recognize awk syntax between `'...'`

2. The awk script outside the shell script

Better solution for long awk scripts.

- Use a non executable awk script
  You need to call your awk `foo.awk` script in the shell with the `awk` command. File `foo.sh`:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

/bin/awk -f foo.awk < input.txt > output.txt
```

You could omit `/bin/` if you have `awk` command in your `PATH` environment variable but it's not really secure.

File `foo.awk`:

```c
{print}
```

Really short. IDE recognize the syntax only with the file extension.

- Use an executable awk script

Use this command `chmod +x foo.awk` in order to put executable flag on your `foo.awk` file.
You don't need to call your awk `foo.awk` script in the shell with the `awk` command.

File `foo.sh`:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

foo.awk < input.txt > output.txt
```

You need to have `foo.awk` directory in your `PATH` environment variable or prefix it with its directory like this : `/my/program/directory/foo.awk ...`

In order to execute the good interpreter, you need to add a shebang line on the first line of your awk script `foo.awk`:

```
#! /bin/awk -f

{print}
```

Some IDE, recognize this file as awk file with extension and in case of doubt, read the first line for doing the better choice.

Comment: Is it possible to use an executable awk script inside a bash script?  Can one have the file `foo.awk` but be able to call it by its name `foo` ?

Comment: You couldn't have a script file into another script file except if you consider my first solution. But we have an unnamed awk script.

Comment: You could call your awk script `foo` instead of `foo.awk`. If you really want to name it `foo.awk` and call it in your shell script `foo`, you need to create a symbolic link : `ln -s foo.awk foo` in your `foo.awk` directory.  I often use symbolic link like that for my scripts. So I have (shell|awk|python|...) scripts with and without extension. It's more simple to use it without extension and if I need to change the language, I don't need to change other script contents. I just change the destination of the symbolic link. Fun with third solution

Comment: You could also call your awk script like this: `awk foo <input.txt >output.txt`. `awk` command search for `foo.awk` if `foo` file does not exists. I don't like this method

Comment: I do not like the method of calling `awk foo`.  But with executable awk file, it would be good to call `foo file` in the command line, as one can do with bash functions.

Comment: I am not sure whether to have `#! /bin/awk -f` in the awk file.  It looks like I would need it so I can call it from the terminal using `foo file`.

Comment: I have seen the use of `awk -f program.awk file1`, so why use `awk -f foo.awk < input.txt > output.txt` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143036/discussion-between-arnaud-valmary-and-gibran).